# Associate ID with Class in CSS

Tags: css

Is there something clever I can do in CSS to indicate that an element with a particular ID should always use one or more classes?  Something like:

```
#user_info_box {
    use-class: ui-widget-content ui-corner-all;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    ...
}
```

Only, you know, using actual valid CSS properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) is perfect for this. Specifically, see "mixins".

```
#user_info_box {
    .ui-widget-content;
    .ui-corner-all;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very cool; I love learning about tools like this.  Do you know how it compares with SASS, recommended in another answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in CSS, however you may be interested in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/try.html)

```
#user_info_box {
  @extend .ui-widget-content;
  @extend .ui-corner-all;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nifty, thank you.  Do you know how it compares with LESS, recommended in another answer?  And can you run it client-side, or is the server-side install mandatory?

Comment: You may take a look at this comparison [SASS vs LESS](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://lesscss.org/

it will give you more flexibility with your CSS including something similar to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Umm no. You could with javascript/jQuery though.