# jQuery CSS classes as LESS mixins

Tags: jquery, less

Courtesy of [another question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123961/associate-id-with-class-in-css/11124024) I recently discovered [LESS.](http://lesscss.org/)  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting it to do what I want.

My .less file looks like this:

```
#user_box {
    .ui-widget-content;
    .ui-corner-all;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 10px; 
    top: 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100; 
    height: 40em; 
    width: 16em;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I'm trying to associate that particular div with that pair of jQuery classes.  However, it doesn't work; the formatting gets ignored entirely.  But when I remove that pair of mixins, it starts working.  (Minus the `#user_box` div getting treated as though it had those two classes, of course.)  That makes me suspect LESS's JS parser isn't able to find those two classes and is aborting.

Am I doing this wrong, or does LESS simply not allow you to pull in other .css files' classes as mixins?  FWIW, I'm placing "stylesheet/less" link and less.js script after all the jQuery link/script calls.

---

**EDIT:**  Mathletics points out that that I need to use an @import statement, but I'm still struggling.  The .less file lives in `/team/css`, and the file I'm trying to import lives in `/team/css/custom-theme`.  None of the following statements work:

```
@import "/team/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css";
@import "custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css";
@import "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css";
```

This is true regardless of whether the `<link type="text/css" href="/team/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />` has been included in the HTML file.

---

**EDIT 2:**  Also, I'm doing LESS client-side; don't know if that impacts anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import/reference any files whose mixins you want to use in the current scope/file.

So, if your mixins are defined in `mixins.less`, your less file should look like this:

```
@import "mixins" /* NOTE THIS IMPORT */

#user_box {
    .ui-widget-content;
    .ui-corner-all;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 10px; 
    top: 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100; 
    height: 40em; 
    width: 16em;
    background-color: white;
}
```

You can't pull in classes from files that the current LESS file doesn't know about. You can, however, use the LESS compiler to combine files for you, so you just have one or two files that import the others, making all your classes available.

---

Thanks to @zzzBov for pointing out that LESS does not parse files with a CSS extension; you'll need to change the extension from `.css` to `.less` for any file whose rules you want to access in LESS.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, though I could be screwing up the execution.  But I need to ask: can I only import other .less files?  Because like I said, I'm trying to pull in jQuery's .css file.

Comment: Can I see your import statements? You should be able to do what you're trying to do. You can import both `css` and `LESS` files.

Answer (score 0):

When imported, CSS files are treated as literal output, and not interpreted by LESS.

Comment: This seems to be true, but have you seen it written in the documentation? Would be great to point to a reference on this.

Comment: It's in the docs under [importing](http://lesscss.org/#-importing): "If you want to import a CSS file, and don’t want LESS to process it, just use the .css extension".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I got this to work.

Download the theme from jqueryUI Theme roller.  Inside the zip there will be a folder for css and the name of the theme.  I used the theme "start".

At the top of your .less file put this.

```
@import "start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.less";
```

It's important to note that the importing is based on where the current file is.  I put my styles.less file inside another folder called css on the root of the server.  So it's important that the theme folder name "start" is right there with it.

Make sure to get rid of any old referneces to the jqueryUI theme .css in your HTML.

Inside the "start" folder you will see images.  Move the images folder to the same directory as your styles.less file.  THIS IS IMPORTANT or else it will not work correctly and you will get errors.  You can see the errors if you use Google Chrome Inspector->console.

Finally you must as Mathletics pointed out change the .css to .less for the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css file (or whatever yours happens to say).  It won't import unless it says .less

The good thing about .less though is it fallsback to normal CSS if no {LESS} related syntax is used, which makes this just WORK :).

Now I can use Mixins from jQuery classes.

Hope this helps someone!